# Adding UIWindow breaks autolayout from background

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uialertcontroller

I'm trying to add UIAlertController in a new window on top of all other views. Works fine except it's trying to break autolayout each time window appears.

```
    let topWindow = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!

    let alertWin = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    alertWin.rootViewController = UIViewController()
    alertWin.tintColor = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!.tintColor
    alertWin.windowLevel = topWindow.windowLevel + 1
    alertWin.makeKeyAndVisible()

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "TITLE", message: text, preferredStyle: .Alert)
    let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { _ in                                    
       alertWin.rootViewController?.presentingViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
       alertWin.hidden = true
       alertWin.rootViewController = nil
       alertWin.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    alert.addAction(OKAction)
    alertWin.rootViewController?.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I have already tried to put both this snippet and action closure content into main thread, but no luck

```
This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread, which can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.  This will cause an exception in a future release.
 Stack:(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ed36d85 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010e0aedeb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ed36cbd +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
    3   Foundation                          0x000000010de22b6b _AssertAutolayoutOnMainThreadOnly + 79
    4   Foundation                          0x000000010dc82357 -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 31
    5   UIKit                               0x0000000111292adb -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _withAutomaticEngineOptimizationDisabledIfEngineExists:] + 58
    6   UIKit                               0x000000011129361e -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) updateConstraintsIfNeeded] + 254
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000111283c47 -[UIWindow(UIConstraintBasedLayout) updateConstraintsIfNeeded] + 108
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000111294333 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsAtEngineLevelIfNeeded] + 272
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000110a48a96 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _updateConstraintsAsNecessaryAndApplyLayoutFromEngine] + 159
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000110a256f6 -[UIWindow layoutSubviews] + 43
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000110a58980 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 703
    12  QuartzCore                          0x0000000110585c00 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
    13  QuartzCore                          0x000000011057a08e _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 366
    14  QuartzCore                          0x0000000110579f0c _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    15  QuartzCore                          0x000000011056e3c9 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 277
    16  QuartzCore                          0x000000011059c086 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 486
    17  QuartzCore                          0x000000011059c378 _ZN2CA11Transaction14release_threadEPv + 224
    18  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001139c8387 _pthread_tsd_cleanup + 470
    19  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001139c7f63 _pthread_exit + 117
    20  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001139c6582 pthread_attr_getschedpolicy + 0
    21  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001139c4341 start_wqthread + 13
)
```

Comment: It isn't breaking autolayout; it is telling you that you modified the UI from a background thread. Dispatch your updates on the main queue. You say you already did this, but this isn't reflected in your code. Please edit your question to show how you did this

Comment: There is no sense to add gcd closures here. I have checked current thread before creating window and inside the closure - always in main.

Comment: Then perhaps this isn't the code that is causing the problem, since the exception is pretty clear

Comment: Well, it is exactly the code code that is causing the problem. And it appears when app is removing window.